# Prove that there is no rational number solution for an equation.

Tags: irrational-numbers

Prove that there is no rational number solution to the equation $x^2-3x+1=0$. 
(Note, we do not assume that we know all the solutions of $x^2-3x+1=0$ are given by quadratic formula)

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the rational root theorem?  You can complete the square, discover (what you could have found from the quadratic formula) the roots involve $\sqrt 5$ and prove $\sqrt 5$ is irrational.

Comment: Assume there is a root of the form ${p \over q}$ with $p,q$ coprime, multiply through by $q^2$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: I was just giving a hint...

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Not at all!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x = \frac{a}{b}$ ($a, b \in \Bbb{Z}$) is a solution to the equation.  Without loss of generality, we may assume that $a$ and $b$ are coprime (so that the fraction is in lowest terms).  Then,
$$
\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^2 - 3\left( \frac{a}{b} \right) + 1 = 0,
$$
and by multiplying by $b^2$,
$$
a^2 - 3ab + b^2 = 0.
$$
Rearranging a bit,
$$
b^2 = a(3b - a),
$$
which shows that $a$ divides $b^2$.  Since $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, Euclid's Lemma says that $a$ divides $1$.  In other words, $a = \pm 1$.

Rearranging the equation a bit differently,
$$
a^2 = b(3a - b),
$$
so $b$ divides $a^2$, which leads to $b = \pm 1$.

So the assumption that $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ leads inexorably to the conclusion that, in lowest terms,
$$
x = \pm \frac{1}{1} = \pm 1.
$$
You can check that those are not roots.

Answer (score 1):

As copper.hat mentioned in his comment, assume $x=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers.  Thus,
$$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{a^2}{b^2}-3\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+1&=&0\\
a^2-3ab+b^2&=&0\\
a^2-2ab+b^2&=&ab\\
(a-b)^2&=&ab
\end{eqnarray}$$
But $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.  So either $a$ and $b$ are both odd or exactly one of them is even.  If $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then the left hand side is even and the right hand side is odd. If exactly one of $a$ or $b$ is even, then the left hand side is odd and the right hand side is even.  Either case results in a contradiction.  Thus $x$ is irrational.

Comment: I'm curious how you plan to finish by using that.

Comment: That's not true, e.g. let $\,a,b = 4,9.\ $

Comment: Yes, one can use parity (in various ways, e.g. see may answer). Done that way, there's no need to rearrange it to get the perfect square (which is why I found the method puzzling).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $x$ is a root of $\,f(x) = x^2\!-3x+1$ then so too is $\,1/x$  (since, by Vieta, the roots have product $=1).$ If $\,x\in\Bbb Q\,$ is in lowest terms then $x$ or $1/x$ has odd denominator, so reducing mod $2$ it yields a root of $f$ modulo $2$, contra $f$ has no roots mod $2,\,$ since $\,f(0)\equiv 1\equiv f(1).\ \ $ **QED**